# Cannot install imagemagick in my server

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2, imagemagick, php-5.5

I am trying to install ImageMagick library in my server. But it is giving me an error. It says

```
Reading package lists... Error! W: Duplicate sources.list entry
http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/sarimkhan/xUbuntu_13.10/
./ Packages
(/var/lib/apt/lists/download.opensuse.org_repositories_home:_sarimkhan_xUbuntu%5f13.10_._Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry
http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/sarimkhan/xUbuntu_13.04/
./ Packages
(/var/lib/apt/lists/download.opensuse.org_repositories_home:_sarimkhan_xUbuntu%5f13.04_._Packages)
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header E: Problem with
MergeList
/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_saucy-updates_universe_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

I am really confused. what should I do now. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long success story:
[apt - How to fix Duplicate sources.list entry? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120621/how-to-fix-duplicate-sources-list-entry)

Long story short:

Open /etc/apt/sources.list in favorite editor, find duplicate lines with repositories and delete duplicates. Then repeat ImageMagick install process.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was really kind of you.

Comment: #deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 16 _petra_ - Release amd64 20131126]/ saucy contrib main non-free

Comment: My file has this line written in it. What should I do now?

Comment: Look into /etc/apt/sources.list.d directory and check for duplicates  in files there.

Comment: additional-repositories.list

Comment: deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/sarimkhan/xUbuntu_13.10/ ./
deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/sarimkhan/xUbuntu_13.10/ ./
deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/sarimkhan/xUbuntu_13.04/ ./
deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/sarimkhan/xUbuntu_13.04/ ./

Comment: additional-repositories.list file has the below written on it. Should I change it?

Comment: Yes, remove 2 duplicate lines, keep one for each version (13.04 and 13.10)

Comment: Now getting this error
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_saucy-updates_universe_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

Comment: I guess that is a different problem

Comment: sorry, and thanks anyway, I guess I have to ask a new question :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem using:

```
sudo aptitude update
```

then run:

```
 sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```